# Bug with NSURLConnection.....?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send the data to server from my IPhone client. It works fine for most values but when i try to send a string like "IPhone+Cocoa" the server shows the string as "IPhone Cocoa". I have tried to google it but without success is there any why of doing it.

Here is my code

```
-(void)sendRequestNSString *)aRequest {

NSMutableURLRequest *request =
     [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kURLRequest]];

NSString *httpBody = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",
[requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8St ringEncoding], 
[aRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8St ringEncoding]];

NSData *aData = [httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:aData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

self.feedURLConnection = 
       [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

I am really having trouble finding the solution for this. Is this a bug or I am wrong some where in my code. is there ant other alternative of doing this

Answer (score 4):

`-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` shouldn't be used for encoding parameter values. It leaves certain special characters (+, &, etc) unencoded (as they should be if you were encoding a URL).

Use the following:

```
NSString *escapedParameter = [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,  (CFStringRef)unescapedParameter, NULL,  CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

Not as pretty as `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`, but you could easily make a macro for this.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/01/iphone-dev-building-proper-mailto-urls.ars was written up back in January when I discovered similar problems with building mailto: URLs to send to `-[UIApplication openURL:]`.

N.B. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and mark accepted answers for your questions (if they're good answers worth accepting, of course).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I had to remove the autorelease though.